# Java: Passing file name and string to the command line

Tags: java

I have a small Java program where I'm trying to pass a text file and one or more strings separated by white spaces at the command line. Inside the text file, I have a list of packages as follows:

```
gui -> awtui swingui swingui -> runner extensions textui -> runner
framework awtui -> runner runner -> framework extensions -> framework
```

Now in my java, I want to list each package and its dependencies by passing the text file and package ame at the commandline as follows:

```
$ java PackageList sample.txt gui swingui
```

When I press enter, I would like to list each package as follows at the console:

```
gui -> awtui swingui
swingui -> runner extensions
```

As you can see, the rest of packages should not appear in the output if they are not passed at the command line as arguments.

Here's my Java code which wish is currently printing all the contents of the file regardless of the command line arguments after file name:

```
public class PackageList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File inputFile = null;
        if (args.length > 0) {
            inputFile = new File(args[0]);
        } else {
            System.err.println("Invalid arguments count:" + args.length);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        BufferedReader br = null;

        try {
            String sCurrentLine;
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)
                    br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below code and comments:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class PackageList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File inputFile = null;
        if (args.length > 0) {
            inputFile = new File(args[0]);
        } else {
            System.err.println("Invalid arguments count:" + args.length);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        BufferedReader br = null;

        try {
            String sCurrentLine;
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
            for(int i=1; i < args.length;i++){  // For loop to  check - args[0] is file name so i = 1 
                boolean isDependencyExist = false; // check dependency
                while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    if(sCurrentLine.startsWith(args[i])){ // If file line starts with arg print
                        System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
                        isDependencyExist = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            if(!isDependencyExist){
                System.out.println(args[i] + " ->");
            }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)
                    br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have tested your approach but unfortunately it does't solve the problem. I 'm still getting the same output, meaning it's printing all package in the text file instead just the specified package and its dependencies

Comment: @bencho what is the text file format? You have next line between to packages right?

Comment: @bencho thats ok. I am asking is there newline between each package? textui -> runner framework /newline awtui -> runner

Comment: yes there is a new line between the package listing but its kind of hard to format the contents here on stackflow. It shoud be like this:    gui -> awtui swingui  , then folowed by new line like:                          swingui -> runner extensions

Comment: @bencho please check the code now. I have edited. But I am not sure it will work or not.

Comment: @bencho **java PackageList sample.txt gui swingui** use this command to run. I think this will help you.

Comment: thanks alot for your review. I have tested the code and it works by printing the each package and its dependencies if they are.But when there is no more dependency,i should have the output like:                     gui -> famework, then passing filename ,gui and framework at the command line should give this output :                     gui ->framwork , framework -> (this should be in new line). I'm trying  pseudocode given below.

Comment: @bencho if there is no dependencies what should do? I didnt get your point

Comment: if there is no more dependencies then i should just print the last dependency and an arrow like this: gui->framework, for example if i pass file name, gui,framework   at commandline,then i should have my output as follows:              gui ->framework ,  framework -> . I hope you got my point now.

Comment: I am accepting your answer. Thanks a lot for your help and effort. My reputation is still low so stackoverflow will not display my vote.

Comment: I am doing that just now. Once again, thanks for your great ideas on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading only args[0] from the command line. You want to read all the other args like this.

After the file has been loaded add

```
for(int i=1; i<args.length;i++)
{
// read args[i]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It better to parse the file content by using Regex or StringTokenizer and put the keys and values into Map.

Then you can lookup the value by the commandline args and print it out.

Pseudocode

```
Map<String, String> deps = new Hashtable.....;
foreach line of file {
    String[] tokens = line.split(" -> ");
    deps.put(tokens[0], tokens[1]);
}
for (int i=1; i < args.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(args[i] + " -> " + deps.get(args[i]));
}
```

Something like that.

Comment: Did you mean`HashMap` instead of `Hashtable`?

Comment: it is just a pseudocode to demo the lookup, both HashMap and Hashtable are fine.

Comment: @Raymond ,let me try this suggestion. I will get back to you. It looks quite promising.